# how to return Json with a list from other classes?

Tags: c#, json, linq, class, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm able to return a list from controller below to view:

```
public ActionResult FillSegment(int siteid)
{
    var segment = db.Segment.Where(c => c.SiteID == siteid).Select(x => new
    {
        SegmentID = x.SegmentID, 
        SegmentName = x.SegmentName
    });
    return Json(segment, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But if i want to do the query operation in other classes, and i call the class from FillSegment Action, how it should return?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FillSegment(int siteid)
{
    SegmentHelper segmenthelper = new SegmentHelper();      
    return Json(segmenthelper.FillSegment(siteid), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

segmenthelper Class:

```
public List<string> FillSegment(int siteid)
{
    using (DBConnection db = new DBConnection())
    {
        var segment = db.Segment.Where(c => c.SiteID == siteid).Select(x => new
        {
            SegmentID = x.SegmentID,
            SegmentName = x.SegmentName
        });
        return segment.ToList(); <-- Cannot convert generic list to generic list?
    }
}
```

Comment: You would be better off creating a view model with those 2 properties(and use `.Select(x => new SomeModel { ... });`) and returning a collection of the model.

Comment: Change `FillSegment`'s return type to `dynamic` (if the helper class & the controller are in the same assembly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases it is probably better to introduce a ViewModel class and return it. You might want to use some mapping library.

```
public class SegmentViewModel
{
    public string SegmentID { get; set; } //not sure if it of string type
    public string SegmentName { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<SegmentViewModel> FillSegment(int siteid)
{
    using (DBConnection db = new DBConnection())
    {
        return db.Segment.Where(c => c.SiteID == siteid).Select(x => new SegmentViewModel
        {
            SegmentID = x.SegmentID,
            SegmentName = x.SegmentName
        });
    }
}

// you can also use JsonResult instead of ActionResult
public JsonResult FillSegment(int siteid)
{
    SegmentHelper segmenthelper = new SegmentHelper();      
    return Json(segmenthelper.FillSegment(siteid), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Select` statement will return you a sequence of anonymous objects with properties `SegmentID` and `SegmentName` and they cannot be converted to list of strings.
You had to change return type of `FillSegment`.

Comment: may i know what is the return type?

Comment: public List<string> FillSegment(int siteid) <-- List<string> is return type.

Comment: thanks for your info, i will try out at office tomorrow.

Comment: You can try change it to `List<Segment>`, add class `Segment` with props `SegmentID` and `SegmentName` and, finally, change select to `.Select(x => new Segment { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure but i think this should work

Controller:

```
     public ActionResult FillSegment(int siteid)
     {
        SegmentHelper segmenthelper = new SegmentHelper();      
        return Json(segmenthelper.FillSegment(siteid), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

Segmenthelper Class:

```
    public list<Segment> FillSegment(int siteid)
    {
        using (DBConnection db = new DBConnection())
        {
            var segment = db.Segment.Where(c => c.SiteID == siteid).Select(x => new
        {
            SegmentID = x.SegmentID,
            SegmentName = x.SegmentName
        }).toList();
        return segment;
        }
    }
```